# Buying/Operating Bitcoin ATM

Tags: legal

I am looking for some assistance in gathering the correct information about starting to buy/run/operate a bitcoin ATM in Los Angeles, CA. I would like to start with one and expand to multiple areas.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a website that advises where I would begin the application process on obtaining a license or banks that deal with Bitcoin ATM's?

Please advise on requested information if anyone knows where to start. That would be greatly appreciated.

Have a wonderful day.